# How can I scale objects along a curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have objects (coins) distributed along a curve. I want them to scale proportionally from bottom to top along this curve.

[image]

Comment: could you please improve your question and tell us exactly what and how it should be scaled? just xy? or all axis? or something else?

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 5):

unfortunately your question is a bit vague. So we have no idea what you want to scale and in which direction.

So i assumed you want to scale x and y and it should get smaller on z axis:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As Chris correctly pointed out in his answer, it is not clear from your question exactly what your goal is.

But if you want to have a proportional scaling of the objects to be instantiated along a curve, then you can solve this as follows:

[image]

Here I simply use the value *Factor* of the node `Spline Parameter`, which returns me a value of $0$ - $1$.

I map this value with `Map Range` to the desired range for a scaling.